# What is difference between put code after await v.s. chain code using ContinueWith

Tags: c#, asynchronous

In my understanding, if I await an async function, then the following code will be wrapped in a delegate and executed after the async function returns:

```
async bool Test()
{
    await byte[] arr = ReadAsync(....)

    // all following code will be wrapped into a delegate
    if (arr != null)
    {
        // Do something

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

It sounds like equal to if I explicitly wrap following code in a ContinueWith:

```
async bool Test()
{
    bool res = await ReadAsync(...)
                    .ContinueWith(t => 
                    {
                        byte[] arr = t.Result;
                        if (arr != null)
                        {
                            // Do something
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
}
```

Are there any differences between these two implementations?

Comment: I wouldn't really say that this one a duplicate because there the poster also has an additional `.Wait()`in the `.ContinueWith()` example. This is the actual mayor difference as the answer explains.

Answer (score 5):

One mayor difference is that if the thread you call `await` from has a `SynchronizationContext`, `await` will schedule the continuation inside that `SynchronizationContext` by default. So after the await you will be back on the same thread as before. You can change that by using `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

With `.ContinueWith()` it is eaxactly the other way around, by default it will be scheduled on an aribitary (threadpool) thread unless you pass `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` to it.

Comment: Thanks. So besides those implementation detail difference, are there any performance impacts or practice suggestions which implementation should be used?

Comment: @codewarrior That isn't an "implementation detail difference", that's something you actually have to think about as a programmer, that can make the difference between working and non-working code (where either can be the non-working code).